# Is any other process to download packages without pip?

Tags: python, django, windows, pip, package

I am stuck to download `pip install fiona` package but still it is not downloaded on my windows 10  system.

1.Help to download fiona package

2.How to control cache packages on pip

Comment: https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona#windows

Answer (score 0):

you can use anaconda to download the package **conda install -c conda-forge fiona**

Answer (score 0):

Yes ! we can download any packages without `pip` by help of `pipwin`.

```
pip install wheel
pip install pipwin
```

and by the help of you can download..

```
pipwin install gdal
pipwin install fiona
pip install geopandas
```

Answer (score 0):

we can ignore to download pip cache package by following steps....

1.Remove a package from cache

`pip cache remove matplotlib`

2.clear all wheel files from pip's cache.

`pip cache purge`

3.get the location of the cache.

`pip cache dir`

4.install a package without using the cache

`pip install --no-cache-dir scipy`

5.configure pip to not use the cache "globally"

`pip config set global.no-cache-dir false`

6. Clear all packages from pip

`pip freeze | xargs pip uninstall -y`